# Run multiple threads in sequence using locks

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, java-threads

I am trying to run 4 threads in sequence like 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1.
And I am using int threadId and AtomicInteger to validate if the current thread is eligible to run or not.
But the 4th thread starts and the execution gets stuck, I am not getting why the thread 3, 2 and 1 are not getting a chance to run.

Here is what I did:

```
public class SequenceDemo implements Runnable{
    
    int threadId;
    static AtomicInteger currentThread = new AtomicInteger(4);
    ReentrantLock lock;
    Condition condition;
    
    public SequenceDemo( ReentrantLock lock, Condition condition) {
        this.lock = lock;
        this.condition = condition;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            lock.lock();
            threadId = Integer.parseInt(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            while(currentThread.get()!=threadId) {
                condition.await();
            }
            
            System.out.println("Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" started executing");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" finished executing");
            
            currentThread.decrementAndGet();
            condition.signalAll();
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        Condition condition = lock.newCondition();
        
        SequenceDemo demo1 = new SequenceDemo(lock, condition);
        
        Thread t1 = new Thread(demo1, "1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(demo1, "2");
        Thread t3 = new Thread(demo1, "3");
        Thread t4 = new Thread(demo1, "4");
        
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();
        
    }
}
```

output: Execution gets stuck after execution of thread 4:

```
Thread 4 started executing
Thread 4 finished executing
```

Comment: The locking in multithreading shouldn't be inside the run() method since that is individual to every thread and does not get shared between threads. Instead do some operation on a shared object between threads (which you pass inside the constructor of the threads.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, you should just pass a new SequenceDemo instance to each thread, otherwise they share the threadId and it's just stuck on the value 4 for all threads. (Took me a few minutes to see haha)

Comment: Thanks @Eskapone, 
Instead of using the threadId variable I directly checked the id in the if condition and just removed the threadId variable from the SequenceDemo class. That worked as expected .We don't need to create new instance of SequenceDemo and pass it to each thread.